# Incorrect Syntax near keyword 'Update'

Tags: c#, sql

I am currently making a software that has an update system, a certain user creates an update, that update is then stored in a database ready for anyone who is able to see it. However, when I attempt an update I get the error code:

Incorrect syntax near 'Update'

The code in use is:

```
private void btnSetUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmboxClassUpdate.SelectedItem == null || rtbSetUpdate.Text == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please make sure you have selected a class and made an update");
        }
        else
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Updates (User_ID,Update,Date,Class) VALUES (@User_ID,@Update,@Date,@Class) ", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_ID", FrmLogIn.User_ID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Update", rtbSetUpdate.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy"));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", cmboxClassUpdate.SelectedItem.ToString());
            try
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
```

If someone could have a look through this and tell me if there is any obvious errors I just can't see (I'm new to databases). If I am unclear about anything please tell me.

Any answers are appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `update` (your column in `Updates`) is likely a reserved word for your DBMS and will need to be escaped if you intend to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'Update' is a reserved keyword.  You can use reserved keywords as column names, but when you reference them, you will need to enclose them in brackets to avoid confusing the command parser.

Try changing the SQL Command to: "INSERT INTO Updates ([User_ID],[Update],[Date],[Class]) VALUES (@User_ID,@Update,@Date,@Class) ".

Enclosing the other column names in brackets is optional.  DATE is also a type name, but I believe it can be used as a column name without causing an issue (probably still a good idea to enclose it in brackets).